# how to filter object with foreach

Tags: php

I would like to delete some informations in my object from the key.

Is it possible to do something likes that:

```
foreach ( $object AS $key => $value ) {

    if ( $key == "abc" ) {

        unset( $object{ $key } );

    }

}
```

When I try it I have:

```
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Thx

Comment: Can you please provide the original object?

Comment: `unset( $object{ $key } );` -> `unset( $object->$key );`

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the problem. Works fine here: http://3v4l.org/gcl8B

Comment: @lucasnadalutti I guess OP named his variable `object`, maybe because it is an object an not an array..

Comment: Oh. You're probably right. Ignore me, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($object as $key => $value)
{
    if ($key === "abc") 
    {
        unset($object->key);
    }
}
```

Although seeing as you know the key (based on your "if") you could just do this:

```
unset($object->abc);
```

Comment: It's to keep the 3 first elements of my object ( if key >= 3 )